# Use keystore for multiple web servers on same host (Same Application)

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, keystore

I have setup SSL on tomcat using a self signed cert/Java Keystore.

I have another web server on the same server for the same application that can use keystore.

Can I use the same keystore for this second server? If so, how do I add the alias for that server?

When I try to run

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias WACS -file server.cer -keystore server.keystore
```

I get a password prompt, and after entering password, get a keytool error :

> java.io.IOException: keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Comment: That is probably because the password you've entered is incorrect. There are two passwords that you may be asked for, the certificate's passphrase and the keystore's password. In this case, you'll have to specify the keystore's password.

Comment: password is correct, as the keystore is currently being used. cert has the same password.